# Prevent Child Inheritence of a parent's ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

According to this code:

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="menuitem1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="menuitem2"/>
     </ContextMenu>
   </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

   <Button Width="100" Height="100"/>
   <Button Width="100" Height="100"/>
</StackPanel>
```

If you right click on the Buttons then ContextMenu will appear, children will inherit their parent’s ContextMenu.
My question is how can I prevent this feature?

Edit: I need a way in xaml if it's possible.

Comment: when should the contextmenu open?

Comment: When right click on the stack panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this solution

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="menuitem1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="menuitem2"/>
     </ContextMenu>
   </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

   <Button Width="100" Height="100">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Visibility="Hidden"/>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
   </Button>
   <Button Width="100" Height="100"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

On the buttons in question, you need to stop a right-click mouse event propagating up to the containing `StackPanel`. You can do this by handling `MouseDown` like this:

```
void button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to handle mouse events is there a better way?